# What evidence is there that 'to' belongs to any particular part of speech?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, parts-of-speech

**Reopen note:**

There is a quite finite and modest amount of evidence in the literature about this issue, which members can record here as they see fit. Less than there is for example about what a noun is or what a verb is, or how to tell what the Subject of a sentence is. It's a simple question, that people need to be able to get answered on a site such as this. It is of continuing interest as more recent questions such as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290534/what-part-of-speech-is-the-word-to) attest to. The fact that people disagree about the outcome of the evidence does not mean that there is too much evidence to be documented. Quite the reverse. They disagree because there is relatively little evidence altogether. However, it is seriously interesting evidence.

**The question**

What part of speech is *to* as in:

- I need *to* know.
- *To* err is human, *to* forgive divine.
- What am I *to* do?

This question is not really about the difference in meaning between the examples. It is a question about what grammatical or syntactic reasons we have to classify this item as a particular part of speech. If arguing that it is 'its own part of speech', I'd like to know what grammatical - but not historical - reasons you have for your claim.

Just to clarify, I'm not asking about what assignment any particular authority or publication gives it. I'm interested to know the reasons *why*. Your own personal insights are also very welcome.

If you're a grammar anorak - like me - then you may want a list of the contenders out there from other grammarians. In no particular order:

- preposition
- subordinator
- non-finite auxiliary verb
- modal verb
- inflectional element

Can you help?

Comment: The *to* is sui generis. We can call it a particle, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#English) does, or a subordinator, as Pullum does, or use a phantasy word invented for the occasion. (And no, it is not a verb, and no longer a preposition, as both Pullum and the top answer to the linked question explain.)

Comment: It's a **Complementizer** in particular, it's part of the _for...to_ [infinitive complementizer](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), which marks infinitive clauses. _For_ marks the subject of the infinitive clause, _to_ marks the verb (which is, of course an infinitive verb form).

Comment: @RegDwight Which Pullum are you referring to? In the CaGEL  it is a subordinator, but in Pullum's own paper (1982) he argues strenuously that it is an auxiliary. Huddleston in CaGEL states ‘it is difficult to find compelling evidence between these two analyses’. Duffley provides many good arguments for preposition-hood. The top answer in your link does state 'to' is no longer a preposition, but does not explain why, just that this is the case. (Wikipedia?*!! - good grief) Anyhow, I want to know what insights thoughtful people who are interested have and for what reasons.

Comment: I voted to reopen this thread. :) -- I agree with you in that the other thread didn't address the meat of your question. It sounds like you are looking for a discussion on the syntax of the "to" infinitival w.r.t. its "to". I don't see why such a discussion wouldn't be allowed to be held among those that might be interested in having it. Perhaps you could change your title to reflect more accurately the type of discussion that you are looking for.

Comment: Note that there is more to that excerpt that you are referring to: 2002 *CGEL* page 1185, "It is difficult to find compelling evidence between these alternate analyses. It would not be impossible to maintain [a], if *to* were assumed to be an auxiliary verb, albeit a rather problematic defective one with no forms other than the plain form.  Some linguists have defended that view. But the case for *to* being a VP subordinator is stronger."

Comment: Good luck with your discussion, if/when this thread gets reopened. :)

Comment: @F.E. Thanks :) Of course you're right about the H&P quote - it's a bit of a funny quote though because Pullum is one of the authors that 'they're referring to! I'm going to have a ponder on a title... Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: The 2002 *CGEL* is actually Huddleston's baby. Many of the individual chapters have specialists as the major/main contributors (with Huddleston as a minor/secondary author). The relevant chapter, Chapter 14 "Non-finite and verbless clauses" has only Huddleston's name on it. Anyway, have fun. :)

Comment: I'd like to see this question reopened, if only because it seems the OP has already reflected on this point and would like to hear what others believe. One could argue that is a POB question though, and no "right" or "best" answer exists.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks. Are you aware of any particular arguments/evidence to back this up this line of thinking? While it's a widely held theory, it's also a bit odd to call *to* a marker because it leads us to ask why the verb still needs marking when the clause itself is already marked as subordinate. Doesn't *quite* get to the matter of what category *to* is either, I don't think, because, presumably complementisers can be pronouns, for example, or nouns or adverbs? (unless I've got that wrong!)

Comment: No, complementizers are simply repurposed uses for other words, which have many other uses as well, often as different kinds of words. As for marking, you seem to be under the impression that redundancy is bad; on the contrary, it's a feature, not a bug. The more redundancy there is, the more likely people are to understand, even when it's hard to understand, even when they'd rather not, even when it's hard to hear. It can be overdone, and often is; but it's possible to be too concise as well.

Comment: @JohnLawler Don't see why some 'redundancy' should be bad. However, there must be some cognitive payoff for processing the item in the first place - with a marker surely to make processing easier. I see no reason why *to* helps us process the VP by marking it. The other problem here is 'markers' don't take code. We can have ***I want to*** but not ***I'd like for***; ***It's unlikely to*** but not ***It's unlikely that***; ***I asked to*** but not ***I asked whether***. This all points to ***to*** heading the VP. What Evidence is there specifically *for* ***to*** being a subordinator/marker?

Comment: To start with, in normal speech almost all such words (articles, auxiliaries, complementizers, prepositions, pronouns) are unstressed, so in practice one hears some syllable with /ə/ in it. There's very little processing involved, since there's a bump in the speech stream where the listener is expecting a bump. Think of them as color-coding, syntactic arrays to take the place of the missing inflectional arrays. That's what they are. As for "Evidence", that depends on your presuppositions; if you're looking for something, you're likely to find it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think this question has been changed to make it sufficiently specific enough to warrant being reopened.

Comment: *"but not* ***It's unlikely that***;" -- Er, how about "It's unlikely that Tom will show up"? :) Hey, look! Your thread is re-opened!

Comment: @F.E. Sorry, the word count in comments prevents very much elaboration! What I meant by 'taking code' (NICE property) is that the content of the rest of the phrase can be ellipted. So we can say "***...but Tom's unlikely to __***" [show up]. But we can't say "***It's unlikely that__***"[Tom will show up]. Don't know whether I'm being successful at being any clearer? (probably not). But yes!!! the threads open :) Thanks for supporting the question. Have any ideas to share?

Comment: @JohnLawler I take your argument about processing - to a point. But either the bump caused by markers serves a 'marking' function or it doesn't. Arguing that the processing's  miniscule doesn't alter the fact that there needs to be a benefit outweighing the cost. In the list given, including Dets, Aux, Preps, Comps all the items (arguably) usually head phrases. Why an exception for ***to***? Furthermore ***to*** like Aux and Prep stop being weak when stranded (bona fide case of 'marking' if there ever was one). Lastly, why no VP marker after aux.s, causative verbs, perception verbs etc?

Answer (score 4):

You can rather easily argue that **to** belongs to its own part of speech. The only evidence you need is that it does not fit into any of the major part of speech categories. You will just construct grammatical tests showing that it is not a noun, not a verb, not a preposition, etc. Following examples suggest that **to** is not a verb or noun, and that other prepositions cannot precede verbs in their base form (respectively).

> *Nobody shall to.
>   
> *The to is ready.
>   *It is hard to see with run.

Of course, you can go on with this type of argument with pretty much any high frequency word until you have so many parts of speech that the concept is no longer useful. Of possible interest is Croft's discussion of Word Classes in *Radical Construction Grammar*.

Comment: I kind of agree. But, that's only if your test shows that it does ***not fit***, and only if your willing to eject from your categories other items on the same basis if they fail comparable tests. I'm not convinced about your actual tests though. The first in particular seems analogous to ***Nobody shall can*** which would rule out *can* from being a verb. So there still seems to be scope for *to* being a verb. If S-conjunctions are prepositions then we have: ***Because try as she might***  regarding the preposition claim. You haven't given any tests for other categories. Can you do so?

Answer (score 1):

One option that doesn't appear on your list is that it isn't even a word.  Perhaps it's merely an open form bound morpheme.

I do see some evidence against its being an affix.  If it is an affix, it's the only affix I know with an open form.  Other affixes have closed or hyphenated forms.  If it is an affix, it's the only affix I know that is occasionally suppressed.  For example, except for the *to*, "I'll help you to do it" and "I'll help you do it" are identical in grammar and meaning.

I also see some evidence for its being an affix. It only appears at the beginning of an infinitive.  The *to* marks the infinitive form of a verb in much the same way as the *-ing* marks the gerund.  The infinitive form is created in other languages by using affixes.

It seems much more likely to me that the infinitive marker is a slightly odd example of inflectional morphemes than that it is the sole example of an entire category of grammatical word function.  That may be slim and subjective, but I count that as evidence against its being a full-fledged word.

Comment: I like the idea. I'm wondering about items that come in between *to* and the plain form of the verb: *to not comply* or *to bravely go*. Do you think this poses a bit of a problem for the clitic/affix proposal?

Comment: Yes, it does pose a problem.  One solution (which I do not endorse) is to declare that the split infinitive is an error.  Another is to claim that those modifiers are, in fact, inserted inside the one-word open form infinitive, which is something we abso-bloody-lutely do in other circumstances, even without the invitation that the open form suggests.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's not the only affix I know that's sometimes suppressed.  The commands "Move quickly" and "Move quick" are the same.  We drop the -ly without changing either the grammar or the semantics.