# What part of speech is the word "to" in "Alice likes to dance"?

Tags: infinitives, parts-of-speech

> Annie likes to dance

What part of speech is the word *to*?

**Reopen note:**

Merriam Webster lists it as [a preposition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) and gives the following definition:

> 8 —used as a function word to indicate that the following verb is an infinitive < *wants to go* > and often used by itself at the end of a clause in place of an infinitive suggested by the preceding context < *knows more than she seems to* >

It doesn't seem to very convincing that *to* is  a preposition when it occurs before a verb like this.

Comment: When *to* indicates that the following verb is an infinitive, it is generally called an *infinitive marker*. Search our site for *infinitive marker* and you will find various questions about how *to* as an infinitive marker.

Answer (score 2):

As used in your example, it's a **subordinating conjunction** (or subordinator for short). It's not actually part of the verb, contrary to what many user manuals will tell you!

Comment: that's made me so happy, remembering an argument at work where I insisted that "to boldly go" is *not* a split infinitive.

Comment: I don't really think *subordinating conjunction* and *subordinator* are exchangeable once you start to include *to* as a subordinator. You seem to rather be taking someone's word for it when you make this claim of *subordinator*-hood for *to* too! It's a massively contentious proposal. Even Pullum, the other co-author of CaGEL, says that it is a non-finite modal verb. Perhaps you might like to explain why you feel it is a subordinator as [an answer to this question here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173962/what-evidence-is-there-that-to-belongs-to-any-particular-part-of-speech)

Comment: Actually, I'd have to get it reopened first ...

Comment: @Araucaria, CGEL (and thus Pullum) concludes that the infinitival marker "to" is a subordinator. Pullum did argue once that it was a defective auxiliary verb, but then stated that its semantic inertness, and occasional optionality ("He helped to clear up" = "He helped clear up"), and its failure to occur in independent clauses all make it look like a subordinator. Pullum issued a paper (last updated 6/14) which contained a tree diagram in which he labels it as 'Sub'.

Comment: @BillJ No, not really. Pullum did not work on that chapter in CaGEL. More problematic is that even CaGEL say that "there is little to choose between the two analyses". And as Bas Aarts says in [Grammatici Certant](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/60221/1/13312.pdf) "*He [Huddleston] notes that ‘some linguists have defended that view’ (p. 1185). This is being a little bit coy, because one of those linguists was Pullum, who defended this analysis at great length (Pullum 1982)*". It's hardly surprising, therefore, that Pullum ducks this in future publications where this is not the main issue.

Comment: And let's face it, if it's a non-finite auxiliary, how exactly is it going to occur in independent clauses?

Comment: Normally "to" is a preposition, in connection with an infiniitive it is an infinitive-particle.

Comment: @Araucaria I'll talk to GKP today and get his current opinion. Will let you know what he says.

Comment: Erm, if you do manage to speak to him, I've had huge difficulty getting hold of: Syncategorematicity and English infinitival to. *Glossa* 16, 181– 215. When I went to the British library they were unable to find that edition of Glossa and there aren't any electronic copies that I know of. Edinburgh don't have a copy either. Does he know where I can get hold of one, please? [The English subordinators was the topic of my original PhD thesis].

Comment: @BillJ [This question here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173962/what-evidence-is-there-that-to-belongs-to-any-particular-part-of-speech) is now open again btw, in case you're tempted at all ...

Comment: @Araucaria I managed to speak to GKP. He said far too much for me to repeat it all here (plus I didn't ask his permission to), but suffice to say that he does indeed support the 'defective auxiliary verb' analysis, despite RDH's contrary opinion. I'm off to ruminate !

Comment: @BillJ I'm incredibly grateful, I can't really tell you how much,. I've spent so much time on that, even though I gave it up several years ago. Whilst not wanting to push my luck to far, I don't suppose you found out how I might get a copy of that paper?

Comment: @Araucaria, Damn! Really sorry, but I forgot to ask. Leave it with me, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, if you can! I'd really appreciate it.